# how to fix this forgotten server compile error?

Tags: c++, compilation

im getting this error when i try to compile the forgottenserver 0.4 trunk

http://pastebin.com/nicLTLsx

and this player.h

http://pastebin.com/37jKu29M

Comment: Please add more details: what does the error look like, what have you tried, what did you try to achieve in the first place ...

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because the code returns `NULL` in functions with a non-pointer return type (like `uint32_t`.) This produces a warning. However, your compiler flags include:

```
-Werror
```

which turns warnings into errors. To work around it, either remove that flag from CXXFLAGS, or append the following flag to the *end* of CXXFLAGS:

```
-Wno-error=conversion-null
```

Ideally, you should report this problem to the maintainer of the project (and probably also mention that using -Werror when shipping code to end users is a bad idea.)

Comment: i removed the -werror flag but that what happen after that

http://pastebin.com/DBWhX3J5

and thats the 


luascript.cpp file

http://pastebin.com/wSugbVmS

i reported the maintainer but they stopped supporting this version because its kinda old 
the problem is most of the ppl prefers this rev.